Is reactive programming more memory-efficient in managing threads for asynchronous operations?
I frequently use Awaitility in my tests to handle asynchronous operations. However, each Awaitility call spawns threads, which results in high memory consumption when running large tests. I'm searching for an alternative solution that provides similar functionality but is more memory-efficient.

Example Scenario:
Below is a simplified example where I need to find 500 random prime numbers between 0 and 10,000,000.
Using Awaitility:
static void waitWithAwaitility() {
    AtomicInteger primeCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
    await()
        .atMost(1, TimeUnit.HOURS)
        .pollInterval(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .until(() -> {
            int number = supplierMethod().get();
            if (isPrime(number)) {
                System.out.println("Found prime: " + number);
                primeCount.incrementAndGet();
            }
            return primeCount.get() >= 500;
        });
}

Helper Methods:
public static Supplier<Integer> supplierMethod() {
    int number = new Random().nextInt(10_000_000) + 1;
    System.out.println("Generated number: " + number);
    return () -> number;
}

public static boolean isPrime(int number) {
    if (number <= 1) return false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) {
        if (number % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

When I profile the memory usage with tools like VisualVM, I notice a significant memory footprint.


Exploring Alternatives:
ChatGPT suggested using reactive programming (with Project Reactor) as an alternative. I tried implementing the solution below:
Reactive Programming Example:
public Mono<Integer> reactiveAwait(
    Supplier<Integer> supplierMethod,
    Predicate<Integer> condition,
    Duration pollInterval,
    Duration timeout
) {
    return Mono.defer(() -> Mono.fromSupplier(supplierMethod))
        .repeatWhen(repeat -> repeat.delayElements(pollInterval))
        .takeUntil(condition::test)
        .last()
        .timeout(timeout, Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Timeout exceeded")))
        .onErrorResume(throwable -> {
            System.err.println(throwable.getMessage());
            return Mono.empty();
        })
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic());
}

static void waitWithJavaRx() {
    AtomicInteger primeCount = new AtomicInteger(0);

    Mono<Integer> result = new DifferentAwaitility().reactiveAwait(
        () -> supplierMethod().get(),
        number -> {
            boolean primeStatus = isPrime(number);
            System.out.println("Is prime? " + primeStatus);
            if (primeStatus) {
                primeCount.incrementAndGet();
            }
            return primeCount.get() >= 500;
        },
        Duration.ofSeconds(3),
        Duration.ofHours(1)
    );

    Integer finalResult = result.block();
    if (finalResult != null) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + finalResult);
    } else {
        System.err.println("Error: Timeout or other failure occurred");
    }
}


Issue with the Reactive Approach:
While this approach works, the memory consumption was three times higher than when using Awaitility. Below are VisualVM screenshots comparing the memory usage:


Awaitility Memory Usage
Reactive Programming Memory Usage


Question:
Is there a better approach to achieving similar functionality as Awaitility but with lower memory consumption? I’ve explored reactive programming, but it didn’t help in reducing memory usage.

Usually I would expect one thread that does the actual calculation, and another one that is polling the state. The state check should be quick, but in your case you are doing the actual calulation within this check. IMHO that's not want you want.
For a baseline I would suggest to start with plain old Java: One separate thread with your calculation and a while-loop in the main thread that is monitoring the progress. Any framework like Awaitility or Reactive will surely make the code more elegant, but they cannot do less than described above, especially not with less resources.

Never used Awaitility, but with large number of threads you would be better off fixing helper methods by replacing new Random() =>ThreadLocalRandom.current() and for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(number); i++) => for (int i = 2, max = (int)Math.sqrt(number); i <= max; i++)

In what way is 2MiB (or 7MiB for that matter) a significant memory consumption? The main thread may be attributed more memory here because it was the thread that triggered class loading for a lot of things.

It is a long thing to cover but I will try to keep it short by covering several points and you choose where to focus:

Creating a thread (or reusing too many of them from a pool) is a high cost operation and as you are trying a boundedElastic thread pool the default is 10 threads per core which can be too many or too few depending on the amount of code to run.

I would argue that consuming memory is not an issue when running in parallel, because usually you run in parallel to reduce the ammount of time it takes, not the ammount of memory that is consumed.

If you want to keep mono you can try to change the Scheduling policy, chatGPT will guide you with that, I would argue bounded is the worst for this sample scenario (parallel, boundedElastic, single, inmmediate,...), see the following answer:
Difference between boundedElastic() vs parallel() scheduler

The higher level you go in threading libraries the more overhead you have of course, it makes sense to me that the default behavior of Mono takes more memory than the default memory of await() in the same scenario and that would take more memory than doing threads by hand (this is more common sense than having tried it myself, but imagine threads in JNI, that would be almost assembler).

In general if you are having memory issues when doing concurrency, you do LESS concurrency or you buy more memory, that sums the whole thing up IMHO.


